# Get user ID on user registering WordPress

Tags: php, database, wordpress, registration

Im building a plugin for wordpress. I want to creat a row in a custom database table i have created called jp_test. I need the wordpress user ID in my custom table. My code do far is in the plugin index file but I have tried it in the theme functions.php too and it still doesnt work. can anyone suggest anything?

```
    function add_to_jp( $user_id ) {        

    global $wpdb;

    $jp_data = array( 
        'wp_user_ID' => $user_id,
        'jp_email' => '',
        'jp_telephone' => '',
        'extra' => ''
    );

    $wpdb->insert(  'jp_test', $jp_data); 

}

add_action( 'user_register', 'add_to_jp)');
```

Comment: I can inform you that the wpdb code works to insert data. its the getting of the users ID and any other data upon registration I cant get to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this ?

```
function add_to_jp( $user_id ) {

    $jp_data = array( 
        'wp_user_ID' => $user_id,
        'jp_email' => '',
        'jp_telephone' => '',
        'extra' => ''
    );

    global $wpdb;

    $wpdb->insert(  'jp_test', $jp_data, array('%d', '%s', '%s', '%s') ); 

}

add_action( 'user_register', 'add_to_jp');
```

Hope this work :/

Comment: Thank you very much for that. how would I get any other data like they're email etc?

Comment: You should can get it from the POST data, it depend of your form. like `if ( isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) )`